# animateIn after another animate issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to create two sets of text that animate with a container. The first text div I am wanting to show on page load and go from the left to the destination point. The second text div I am wanting to start animating after the first text div, which for some reason isn't working in my snippet? I will post a jsfiddle in the comment section.

However, my second text div, is not working as I am wanting it to. You can see in the first text div, that it animates in from the left until it gets to its destination point. I am trying to do the same with the second text div, but it only fades in to its full opacity, and does not animate from the top down.

Does anyone see why?

```js
$(function() {
    $("#text_div").animate(
        {left : "37%"}, 500, function() {}
    );
});
function animateIn(divId, callback) {
    $("#text_div2").animate(
        {opacity:1.0},
        {top : "67%"},
        700,
        callback,
        function() {});
}
$("#text_div").animate(
    {opacity:1.0}, 700, 
    function() {
        animateIn("#text_div2");
    }
);
```

```css
#container {
 margin: 20px 10%;
 height: 300px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 position: relative;
 top: 70px;
}
#text_div {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
 top: 40%;
 clear: both;
 font-size: 3em;
}
#text_div2 {
    opacity:0;
    top: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:#00CCCC;
    font-size: 2em;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
 <div id="text_div">My writing</div>
  <div id="text_div2">Second set</div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=rrL8Hn83AD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of the `animate` function was incorrect, change it to this:

```
function animateIn(divId, callback) {
    $("#text_div2").animate({opacity:1.0, top : "67%"}, 700);
}
```

The CSS properties should be grouped together with the curly braces as the first parameter :)

Comment: I uploaded this to my site and the second text div isn't waiting for the first div to finish? Do you have any idea why? http://realtorcatch.com/animate_test

Comment: You have another `animate` function that is independently animating the first `div` on your page

Comment: So what does that mean I should do?

Comment: Remove the code that is independently animating the first `div`

Comment: Gotcha. I figured it out. I removed the bottom code, but moved up the function `animateIn("#text_div2");` into the first block. Thanks!

Comment: Thats another solution as well resulting in the code  :) And Your welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

The css properties to animate has to be specified as a single object, in this case both opacity and top values

```js
$(function() {
  $("#text_div").animate({
    left: "37%"
  }, 500, function() {});
});

function animateIn(divId, callback) {
  $("#text_div2").animate({
      opacity: 1.0,
      top: "67%"
    },
    700,
    callback);
}
$("#text_div").animate({
    opacity: 1.0
  }, 700,
  function() {
    animateIn("#text_div2");
  }
);
```

```css
#container {
  margin: 20px 10%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  top: 70px;
}
#text_div {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 40%;
  clear: both;
  font-size: 3em;
}
#text_div2 {
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #00CCCC;
  font-size: 2em;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="text_div">My writing</div>
  <div id="text_div2">Second set</div>
</div>
```